# Communication between sibling components in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I have two sibling components and one needs to send data to the other one. The communication should happen between the heroes component and encounters component:

```
<section id="Dashboard" >
 <app-heroes></app-heroes>

 <app-monsters></app-monsters>

 <app-encounters></app-encounters>
</section>
```

I have [uploaded the UI to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNOsy.jpg) to clarify the issue. When someone clicks on one of the heroes, the hero that has been clicked should be added to "Heroes" in the encounter component.

I created a shareservice:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {Hero} from '../model/hero';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedHeroService {
 private hero = new Subject<Hero>();
 public  hero$ = this.hero.asObservable();

 publishHero(heroToPublish: Hero){
  this.hero.next((heroToPublish));
 }  
}
```

for which I created the following method in my heroes component:

```
addToEncounter(hero){
this.sharedService.publishHero(hero);
}
```

and added the following in my Encounters component:

```
@Input() public heroesAdded = [];
@Input() hero: Hero;
private subscriber: Subscription;

constructor(private sharedHeroService: SharedHeroService) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.subscriber = this.sharedHeroService.hero$.subscribe(hero =>{this.hero = 
hero; this.monstersAdded.push(hero)});
}
```

The html for the Heroes component is:

```
<ul class="heroes">
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <span class="badge" onclick="addToEncounter(hero)">{{hero.name}}</span> 
Hitpoints: {{hero.hitPoints}} Armor: {{hero.armor}}
</li>
```

But when I click on the badge, I get the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: addToEncounter is not defined
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick

I googled this and people are saying the onclick() should never be used, but I don't really get the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **`(click)`** instead of **`onClick`**

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <span class="badge" (click)="addToEncounter(hero)">{{hero.name}}</span> 
Hitpoints: {{hero.hitPoints}} Armor: {{hero.armor}}
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe how easy it was.

Comment: I had to wait a certain time before I could mark it, dunno why but I did now !